# SPI postgresql - insert data into table from postgres.c

Tags: postgresql, database-internals

I'm working inside postgres.c (inside exexc_simple_query) of postgresql 9.1 (line 1094 of http://doxygen.postgresql.org/postgres_8c_source.html#l00829 ). I need to insert some query information  in a table that I will check in a second moment.
I'm trying to do it with SPI using these three lines:

```
SPI_connect();
SPI_exec("INSERT INTO testvalues (11,6)", 5);
SPI_finish();
```

but when I start the server and I send a query I get segmentation fault:

```
LOG:  server process (PID 13856) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2013-07-14 00:40:22 CEST
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/17D7368
LOG:  redo is not required
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix it? Is there a better way to insert data from the postgres.c?

Comment: "inside postgres.c". Er. *where* inside `postgres.c`? Function name and line number? PostgreSQL version? In general, that's not the file I'd choose to modify to do database access..

Comment: Thank you for helping me. http://doxygen.postgresql.org/postgres_8c_source.html#l00829 line 1094 of postgresql 9.1. I also modified the question with this detail.

Comment: Seems like a downright bizarre thing to do. You're trying to fire a query via the SPI just before returning success to the client? Why? What query? Please show the *exact code* you've added and explain what you're trying to achieve with it. You'll also want to get a backtrace - see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD . Again, comment here when edits made, as notifications aren't sent when you do an edit, only when you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. 
SPI functions must be inside the transaction and in my case between `start_xact_command` and `finish_xact_command`.

Comment: But why, oh why?  (see Craig's comments)

Comment: What why? Do you mean why I'm trying to do a query via the SPI before returning success? Or you mean why between those command?

Comment: @DarkCoffee "but why" are you trying to do *anything* with the SPI inside the basic protocol routines! What are you trying to *achieve* with this? How will your change interact with the user's own transaction handling (if they do an explicit `BEGIN`, say)?

Comment: I want to check some parameters before ending the transaction in order to stop it if the check fails.